# Git make patch or backup file containing actual files

Tags: git, backup, patch

In my git repository, I have few git track file modified and few untrack files modification. Is it possible to make a git patch or zip file that will contain all actual files both track and untrack files. That patch/zip file could be unpacked to view file contains even outside of that git repository. It is mainly to make a backup file. Is it possible to do it by git? If not how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To backup only files that are tracked by git, you can use `git-archive`

e.g. `git archive -o latest.zip HEAD`

To backup all files (including untracked) you will have to use another utility such as `zip` or `tar`